# Kendo UI Core and Accessibility

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, accessibility, kendo-mobile

For Kendo UI Core, are all of the accessibility features shown on the Kendo UI Professional website available to core as well?

For example:

"Kendo UI the first HTML5 framework to provide full ARIA support for its web widgets. We closely followed the W3C Widget Design Patterns in the WAI-ARIA specification, and will automatically add the necessary role value and additional attributes, based on the widget in question."

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/accessibility/wai-aria-support-in-kendo

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between Kendo UI Core and Kendo UI Professional is in the widget set, not in the feature set. So the answer to your question is yes, the accessibility features are available in Kendo UI Core as well.

Comment: Yep, to extend your answer, I recommend check this [page](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison) to see what widgets are available in each versions.